# Bubbling Issue with Fancybox and Hoverintent

Tags: jquery, fancybox, hoverintent

I'm using a combination of fancybox (v2.1.5) and hoverintent (v1.8.0) to open a larger image when the user mouses over a thumbnail and then close the larger image when the mouse moves away.
This works perfectly in Chrome 41.0.2272.104 on my iMac. However, when I view it in Firefox 36.0.4 the larger image flashes on and off continuously while the mouse is stationary over the thumbnail. I'm using a trackpad.

Here's some HTML:

```
<a class="fancylink" href="./custom/img/parts/blah.jpg" title="Blah">
    <img src="./custom/img/parts/blah.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
</a>
```

and the code inside the jQuery document ready function:

```
    function openFancybox () {
      $(this).trigger("click");
    };
    function closeFancybox () {
      $.fancybox.close(true);
    };
    $(".fancylink").fancybox({
    closeClick : true,
    openEffect : "none",
    helpers : {
      title : {
        type : "inside"
      },
      overlay : {
        css : {
          "background" : "rgba(238,238,238,0.15)"
          }
        }
      }
    }).hoverIntent(openFancybox, closeFancybox);
```

Can anyone explain why this works in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Comment: Does this http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/mouseEnterLeave_30jul12.html work for you?

Comment: That uses an older version of fancybox. But yes, it does work. Something changed in the new fancybox? Perhaps I should revert to the old version.

Comment: It doesn't really matter the version of fancybox as long as you use the right API options for the version you are using. I will try to make a demo with the new version of fancybox and come back to you later

Comment: OK, here it is the demo using fancybox v2.1.5 and hoverintent v1.8.0 http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/mouseEnterLeave_24mar15.html ... does it work for you?

Comment: **IMPORTANT** notice you should turn the fancybox overlay off because it will trigger the `mouseleave` event (check the source code of my demo)

Comment: Thank you for the new example. Turning the overlay off helps to some extent. If you view my test site at: http://www.millport57995489.us/paddlewheels3.php you will see all is OK in Chrome but some images still flash in Firefox.

Comment: They flash because when fancybox opens, it actually covers the thumbnails (where the hoverintent is applied) so it triggers the `mouseleave` event (when the mouse is not hovering the thumbnail but the opened fancybox.) You either need to redefine your layout so the hovered thumbnail is always visible (and the pointer can remain hover) or close fancybox manually instead of mouse leave (or you may need to bind more events to close fancybox when is not hovering the thumbnail and/or the fancybox itself)